# Python - speed up iteration between nested dictionary

Tags: python, performance, loops, dictionary, openpyxl

I want ask you for some advice to speed up my code. I know that you can see many of mistakes, but I need your knowledge and help where problem lies and how I can improve this code.

**Background - what application creates:**

1. Use OpenPyXL
2. Open excel file, read data and put it into nested dictionary:
   2a. 1st level for rows
   2b. 2nd level for items
   Example:

> {1: '@5C\Qopen@', 2: '20386239', 3: '3000133215', 4: 'RA', 5: None,
> 6: 'Vendor2', 7: 'IM45', 8: '@FR\QNot due@', 9: None, 10: None, 11:
> 'E1', 12: 'DNS', 13: datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 27, 0, 0), 14:
> datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 26, 0, 0), 15: -21501, 16: 'GBP', 17:
> -21501, 18: 'GBP', 19: datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 26, 0, 0), 20: datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 9, 0, 0)}
>
> {2: '@5C\Qopen@', 2: '20386239',
> 3: '3000133215', 4: 'RA', 5: None, 6: 'Vendor1', 7: 'IM45', 8:
> '@FR\QNot due@', 9: None, 10: None, 11: 'E1', 12: 'DNS', 13:
> datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 27, 0, 0), 14: datetime.datetime(2019, 12,
> 26, 0, 0), 15: -21501, 16: 'GBP', 17: -21501, 18: 'GBP', 19:
> datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 26, 0, 0), 20: datetime.datetime(2020, 2,
> 9, 0, 0)}
>
> {3: '@5C\Qopen@', 2: '20386239',
> 3: '3000133215', 4: 'RA', 5: None, 6: 'Vendor1', 7: 'IM45', 8:
> '@FR\QNot due@', 9: None, 10: None, 11: 'E1', 12: 'DNS', 13:
> datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 27, 0, 0), 14: datetime.datetime(2019, 12,
> 26, 0, 0), 15: -21501, 16: 'EUR', 17: -21501, 18: 'GBP', 19:
> datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 26, 0, 0), 20: datetime.datetime(2020, 2,
> 9, 0, 0)}

3. Script should look via whole data - comparing Vendor & Currency and look whether in particular vendor we have different currencies (I mean e.g. when **Vendor 1** doesn't have 100% one specific currency [GBP or other]
4. When this will happened - put text "something something" for example in column "17" in the same row where different currency is
5. Mainly my code works properly **but** its very slow. I mean when I need compare in the same time file with **30 000** rows.

Do you know how I can improve it?
Thank you

```
next_row2 = 1
numerkolumny = 1
nastepny = 1
numer_vendora = 1
ilosc_gbp = 0
ilosc_inne = 0
linijkadanych = {}

lista_vendorow = {}

for zmienna2 in progressbar.progressbar(assets2, redirect_stdout=True):

    for iteracja in assets2:
        if assets2[zmienna2][6] not in lista_vendorow.values():

            if nastepny < len(assets2):
                if assets2[zmienna2][6] == assets2[nastepny+1][6]:
                    if assets2[nastepny+1][16] == "GBP": # JESLI ZNALAZLES GBP, POLICZ DO GBP
                        ilosc_gbp = ilosc_gbp + 1
                        nastepny = nastepny + 1
                    else:                               # JESLI ZNALAZLES INNA WALUTE, POLICZ DO INNEJWALUTY
                        ilosc_inne = ilosc_inne + 1
                        nastepny = nastepny + 1
                else:
                    nastepny = nastepny + 1

            if nastepny >= len(assets2): # JESLI PRZEITEROWALES PRZEZ WSZYSTKIE WIERSZE, OBLICZ WYNIK

                    suma_walut = ilosc_gbp + ilosc_inne # SUMUJ WSZYSTKIE WALUTY

                    # JESLI ZNAJDZIE ODCHYLELNIA - RAPORTUJ!
                    if (suma_walut != ilosc_gbp) and (suma_walut != ilosc_inne):

                        for waluty in assets2: # nr wiersza
                            for waluty2 in assets2[waluty]: # nr kolumny
                                if assets2[waluty][6] == assets2[zmienna2][6]:
                                    if ilosc_gbp > ilosc_inne:
                                        result_tab.cell(column=17, row=waluty+1, value="Waluta other than GBP. Check!").font = style_blad_bold
                                    else:
                                        result_tab.cell(column=17, row=waluty+1, value="Other currencies between GBP!. Check!").font = style_blad_bold

                    lista_vendorow[numer_vendora] = assets2[zmienna2][6]
                    ilosc_gbp = 0   # ZERUJ ZMIENNE, LICZYMY NOWEGO VENDORA
                    ilosc_inne = 0  # ZERUJ ZMIENNE, LICZYMY NOWEGO VENDORA
                    nastepny = 1    # ZERUJ ZMIENNE, LICZYMY NOWEGO VENDORA
                    numer_vendora = numer_vendora + 1
```

Comment: This question are better suited at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @stovfl is right, this is better suited for Code Review. As an aside, it’s going to take the entirety of your program, and some data, to improve the performance.